# How do I run code for every class in jquery? (without using .click or something)

Tags: jquery, class, loops

This is a really simple question, and I thought .each would work but I can't seem to figure it out. I have two classes and for each of these classes I want to run code (the html is being looped out)... however it seems to be only working for the first occurrence of it, and I have no idea how to make this work for every occurrence of it.

```
  var mheight = $('.messagetext, .smessagetext').height();
   if (mheight > 64) {
        var getthis = $('.messagetext, .smessagetext');
        getthis.siblings('.mopacity').show();
        getthis.parents(".messagecontent").siblings('.messagefooter').children('.mspmore, .mfpmore').show();
    }
```

so when I have .click with .messagetext and smessagetext it works fine (as to be expected) yet if it's not done on a click, and I just want to run this for every occurrence of this class, it doesn't work... I'm aware this is jquery 101 but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) method returns the height of the first item in the jquery object.

> Description: Get the current computed height for the **first element in the set of matched
>   elements**.

Change to this:

```
$('.messagetext, .smessagetext').each(function() {

    var $this = $(this),
        mheight = $this.height();

    if (mheight > 64) {
        $this.siblings('.mopacity').show();
        $this.parents(".messagecontent").siblings('.messagefooter').children('.mspmore, .mfpmore').show();
    }

});
```

Comment: +1 for documentation and showing the use of `$this` further down the code - I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

The magic word is `$(this)`:

```
$('.messagetext, .smessagetext').each(function(index) {
    var mheight = $(this).height();
    if (mheight > 64) {
        //....
    }
});
```

When you invoke `.height();` on a collection it will indeed take only the first in the collection.